# How to Search Struct (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, struct, uisearchbar

I am changing my 2 arrays...

```
var title = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"]
var artist = ["Artist 1", "Artist 2", "Artist 3"]
```

...to a struct

```
struct Song {
    var title: String
    var artist: String
}

var songs: [Song] = [
    Song(title: "Title 1", artist "Artist 1"),
    Song(title: "Title 2", artist "Artist 2"),
    Song(title: "Title 3", artist "Artist 3"),
]
```

I set up my `UITableView` so that the title of the cell equals `songs[indexPath.row].title`, and the subtitle of the cell equals `songs[indexPath.row].artist`.

But, I want to be able to search the `UITableView` with a `UISearchBar`. Whenever I just had the variables and not the struct, it worked fine. But, now I am finding an error on

```
var filteredTitles:[String] = []
var searchActive : Bool = false

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filteredTitles = title.filter //the error ({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text as NSString
        let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
        if(filteredTitles.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

As you can see, on the line `filteredTitles = title.filter` it calls my old variable, `title`. What should I replace this line with so that it searches the struct's title?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `filteredTitles` to be an array of `Song` (and rename it to `filteredSongs`.

Then update the call to `filter` such that `text` is replaced with `song` and you access the `title` property of `song`.

And there is no need to cast the title to `NSString`.

Here's your code with the needed changes:

```
var filteredSongs = [Song]()
var searchActive = false

func searchBar(searchText: String) {
    filteredSongs = songs.filter { (song) -> Bool in
        return song.title.range(of: searchText, options: [ .caseInsensitive ]) != nil
    }

    searchActive = !filteredSongs.isEmpty

    self.myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

This assumes `songs` is your array of songs.

Note there is a lot of other cleanup too.

And you probably need to update your table view data source methods to deal with `filteredSongs` being an array of `Song` instead of an array of `String`.