# How to search tableview using data from API?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have built a Tableview that shows data called from an API (I mention this because maybe my problem is due to reloadData()).

However, the format of my data is simple (a struct) and I found an answer that addresses my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875057/how-to-search-struct-swift).

But this didn't work for me. I'm not sure why. My code gets built and there are no errors, but when I search for something, nothing happens.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import UIKit

class UsersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var dataTableView: UITableView!

    var userData: [User] = [
        User(name: "name1", email: "email1", age: 25),
        User(name: "name2", email: "email2", age: 25),
        User(name: "name3", email: "email3", age: 25)
    ]

    var searchedUser = [User]()
    var searchActive = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = dataTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! UsersTableViewCell

        if searchActive {
            cell.userName.text = self.searchedUser[indexPath.row].name // Maybe my error is that I'm just searching for their usernames, but that's what I want
        } else {
            cell.userName.text = self.userData[indexPath.row].name
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchActive {
            return  self.searchedUser.count
        } else {
            return  self.userData.count
        }

    }

}

extension UsersViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchedUser = userData.filter{(user) -> Bool in
            return user.name.range(of: searchText, options: [ .caseInsensitive ]) != nil
        }

        searchActive = true

        self.dataTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Did you connect delegates? `dataTableView.delegate = self; dataTableView.dataSource = self; searchBar.delegate = self;`

Comment: Does the return function get called ? And do you set delegate and data source for TableView?

Comment: Thanks! The delegate and data source are what were missing. But now, after I search I get an empty table. How do I go back to my full table after emptying the search bar?

Comment: Set searchActive to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your Delegates and DataSource:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  dataTableView.delegate = self 
  dataTableView.dataSource = self 
  searchBar.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. But now after searching, my table is empty. And I tried setting searchActive to false in a pull to refresh method but that didn't work. Where should I do it?

Comment: Inside ```searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)```
you can check 
```if searchText == "" {
searchActive = false
self.dataTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Oh wait. My search results are showing up twice (almost like it's looping through `searchedUser` twice). Do you know how that might have happened?

Comment: Maybe clear the ```searchedUser``` before ```searchedUser = userData.filter```
Let me know if that works